# Typescript type inference failure?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I wrote a function to project an Array into a Map:

```
function toMap<T,TKey,TElement>(items: Array<T>,
        keySelector: (item: T) => TKey,
        elementSelector: (item: T) => TElement
    ): Map<TKey,TElement> {

    var map = new Map<TKey,TElement>();
    for (var item of items) {
        map.set(keySelector(item), elementSelector(item));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Basically, iterate through the list and call a user-provided projection function to extract a key and value for the Map.

Note that the types TKey and TElement are infered from the return value of the projection functions being passed in.

Most of the time, the *value* in the map is simply the original element:

```
var personBySocial = toMap(people, person => person.ssn, person => person);
```

So I'd like to make that second lambda the default. Easy enough:

```
function toMap<T,TKey,TElement>(items: Array<T>,
        keySelector: (item: T) => TKey,
        elementSelector: (item: T) => TElement = item => item
    ): Map<TKey,TElement> {

    var map = new Map<TKey,TElement>();
    for (var item of items) {
        map.set(keySelector(item), elementSelector(item));
    }
    return map;
}
```

However, this produces a compile error:

```
Type '(item: T) => T' is not assignable to type '(item: T) => TElement'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'TElement'.
```

For some reason, if I pass `item => item` in separately, Typescript can infer that TElement == T, but if I pass it in as a default, it can't.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a current limitation of Typescript? If it's the latter, does anyone know if it's a known problem that will be addressed in the future?

---

EDIT, in response to Ryan's comment:

```
function toMap<T,TKey>(items: Array<T>, keySelector: (item: T) => TKey): Map<TKey,T>;
function toMap<T,TKey, TElement>(items: Array<T>, keySelector: (item: T) => TKey, elementSelector: (item: T) => TElement): Map<TKey, TElement>;
function toMap<T,TKey, TElement>(items: Array<T>, keySelector: (item: T) => TKey, elementSelector?: (item: T) => TElement): Map<TKey, TElement> {
    var map = new Map<TKey, TElement>();
    if (elementSelector)
        for (var item of items)
            map.set(keySelector(item), elementSelector(item));
    else
        for (var item of items)
            map.set(keySelector(item), item);
    return map;
}
```

I'm running into the same type error, where the map.set in the else clause (`map.set(keySelector(item), item)`) is triggering the error on the second `item` that "T is not assignable to parameter of type TElement".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably better off writing this as two signatures:

```
function toMap<T,TKey>(items: Array<T>, keySelector: (item: T) => TKey): Map<TKey,T>;
function toMap<T,TKey,TElement>(items: Array<T>, keySelector: (item: T) => TKey, elemSelector: (item: T) => TElement): Map<TKey,TElement>;
/* implementation signature here */
```

This would be solvable with [generic type defaults](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175) (you would write `<T, TKey, TElement = T>`), but those have not been merged in yet.

The legitimate complaint about your code, from the compiler's perspective, is that someone might manually specify all the type parameters, but not specify the optional argument:

```
let x = toMap<string, number, boolean>(someStringArray, someNumberFunc);
```

Comment: That complaint makes perfect sense.  I'm running into the same type error when I tried to implement your first example (two signatures). I included my code in my post.